# svg clip-path для блока на весь экран с пропорциями

Tags: css, html5, svg, анимация

Пытаюсь использовать svg `clip-path` для картинки:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  
  background: rgba(74,92,18,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(74,92,18,1)), color-stop(39%, rgba(74,92,18,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(36,43,9,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);

}


#maskandgif{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  
  
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip-path);
  clip-path: url(#clip-path);
}
```

```html
  <div class="box">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="0" width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <defs>
          <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="clip-path">
            <path d="M10 24.003v-3.973h-7l3.76-6.016h-2.877l3.833-5.994h-1.979l5.768-8.017 5.767 8.017h-1.979l3.833 5.994h-2.877l3.751 6.016h-7v3.973h-3zm-2.311-16.983h1.854l-3.833 5.994h2.873l-3.771 6.016h6.188v3.973h1v-3.973h6.177l-3.751-6.016h2.874l-3.834-5.994h1.855l-3.816-5.304-3.816 5.304z"/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
      </svg>
      <div id="maskandgif">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1450175178156-cb9ecd3da179?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Но ничего не отображается.

`clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox` - не помогает, а даже наоборот.

**Вопрос:** Как правильно задать `clip-path` svg для блока или медиа объекта, пропорционально и на всю высоту и ширину?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы не мучаться в SVG c масштабированием и позиционированием, использую следующую технику:

- Есть картинка из которой нужно будет вырезать клип в форме ёлочки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Размеры картинки `600х338px;`

- Для прорисовки `clipPath`, который будет согласован по размерам и
  позицией расположения на картинке, пишем простенький файл:

```html
<svg   width="600" height="338" viewBox="0 0 600 338">
   <image
   xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4qIQ.jpg"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"/>
</svg>
```

Открываем его с помощью векторного редактора и инструментом- `"Рисовать кривые Безье и прямые линии"` рисуем контур:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем файл и забираем из него патч контура ёлочки

Этот патч будет использоваться в качестве `clip=path` для вырезания контура ёлочки из картинки

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="600" height="338" viewBox="0 0 600 338" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
<defs>
 <clipPath id="clip">
   <path d="M300.1 5.8L250.4 65.8 285.1 65.8 200.2 132.6 274.7 131 190.4 217.4 239 217.4 150 291.4 291.3 291.4 291.3 329.7 308.4 329.2 307.8 291.4 450.1 291.4 375.1 217.4 423.2 217.4 332.2 130 400.5 131.6 309.4 65.8 350.3 65.8 300.1 5.8z"
   fill="black"
   stroke="black"/>
 </clipPath>
 
</defs>
 <image id="img1"
 xlink:href=https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4qIQ.jpg"
 width="100%"
 height="100%"
 clip-path="url(#clip)" />

</svg>
```

Для получения адаптированного изображения убираем фиксированные размеры в пикселях, оборачиваем SVG дивом в котором и задаем проценты ширины и высоты

```css
.conyainer {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 600 338" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
    <defs>
     <clipPath id="clip">
       <path d="M300.1 5.8L250.4 65.8 285.1 65.8 200.2 132.6 274.7 131 190.4 217.4 239 217.4 150 291.4 291.3 291.4 291.3 329.7 308.4 329.2 307.8 291.4 450.1 291.4 375.1 217.4 423.2 217.4 332.2 130 400.5 131.6 309.4 65.8 350.3 65.8 300.1 5.8z" fill="red"
       stroke="black"/>
     </clipPath>
     
    </defs>
     <image id="img1" xlink:href=https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4qIQ.jpg"
     width="100%"
     height="100%"
     clip-path="url(#clip)" />
    </svg>
</container>
```

**Update**

Для clip-path, mask годен только svg c одинарными линиями.

svg контуры, нарисованные в векторном редакторе лепкой, калиграфическим пером не будут работать в качестве `clip=path` и `mask так как у них двойные контуры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрите хороший [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/923043/2874)  Павла Варшавского, который демонстрирует это.

Вырезается пространство только между двумя соседними контурами, а внутри нет

Comment: Все здорово, но фона нет и вопрос был по существующему `path` и `svg`, а не вырезать! Ведь я писала что может быть и не картинка и вообще что угодно на фоне, возможно видео. Да и еще вопрос, почему "патч" ? )))))) если па [зс] `θ`

Comment: я так думаю  стоит написать о том что не любой svg path можно использовать для clip-path

Comment: @HamSter ты писала, как правильно задать clip-path, так вот path в нём участвует

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, "нарисуйте", "отрисуйте" сожмите и прочее и покажите рабочий пример! Вопрос не 
 конкретно о clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox чтобы добавлять его в вопрос!!!! Вопрос в общем и целом для любого path можно ли сделать clip-path или нет и можно ли задавать размеры или нет!

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, вот так сразу нужно результат, а потом уже рассуждения)))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, за "Update" отдельное спасибо! ) Подожду еще ответ от Павла )

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, какая ссылка??? Либо тут разместите ответ, либо прошу Вас не тревожьте бессмысленными комментариями и ссылками!) P.S нужна моя елочка

Answer (score 3):

Вот о чём я говорил что ваша ёлочка имеет маленький размер и потому её не было видно 
так же я добавил `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink` что позволяет работать с ссылками в svg вот ваша елочка

В данном случае viewBox не имеет значения так как он не работает с clip-path

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  
  background: rgba(74,92,18,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(74,92,18,1)), color-stop(39%, rgba(74,92,18,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(36,43,9,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);

}


#maskandgif{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  
  
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip-path);
  clip-path: url(#clip-path);
}
```

```html
  <div class="box">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      height="0" width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="clip-path">
            <path d="M 229.04205,492.61186 V 413.80304 H 27.044554 L 135.54606,294.46906 H 52.525095 L 163.13315,175.57146 H 106.02557 L 272.47151,16.545439 438.88859,175.57146 h -57.10758 l 110.60806,118.8976 H 409.3681 L 517.6099,413.80304 H 315.61241 v 78.80882 z m -66.68803,-336.8765 h 53.50047 L 105.24644,274.63295 h 82.90555 L 79.333048,393.96693 H 257.89883 v 78.80882 h 28.85679 V 393.96693 H 465.00398 L 356.76218,274.63295 h 82.9344 L 329.05967,155.73536 H 382.589 L 272.47151,50.524679 Z"/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
      </svg>
      <div id="maskandgif">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1450175178156-cb9ecd3da179?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Вот, супер! Спасибо!

Comment: @HamSter я вам с утра пишу вы молчите как партизан...лан главное Александр сделал и вас устроило

Comment: бывает мелочь и ее понять сложно пока не увидишь наглядно в чем причина. Про добавить `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink` и не подумала бы. Александр помог тем что подсказал, path должен быть закрытым контуром ну и плюс о размерах.

Comment: @HamSter я о размере елочки с утра писал ... что она маленькая

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский главное слышать друг друга. Вы оба были правы и не правы. Всё зависит куда смотреть. Я писал, что path c двойным контуром не вырезает, потому что работает только пространство между соседними контурами смотри скриншот под моим Update, а внутреннее пространство не работает/ Я привел ответ, когда работает внутренне пространство в клипе и размеры клипа привязаны к объекту

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я же path взяял с вопроса ... и не перерисовывал же ...  всё осталось как и было

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я с утра писал что ёлочка меленькая ...молчок ..я подумал что я за тупил ..аж каплю передумал делать ..надулась вена во лбу ...но явно было видно по координатам что маленький размер ...но правда ошибся в том что нужен был aspectRatio

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский опять не вчитываешься в мой комментарий :))) Вырезание идет у тебя между двумя контурами одного патча, а не внутри контура. Вообще такие споры полезны, помогают разобраться глубже в вопросе

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ну ладно ...я всё равно брал svg из вопроса ... главное помогли а остальное второстипенно ... пока

Answer (score 2):

Решил, чтобы не мешать всё в одну кучу и не запутать дать второй ответ.

Вся структура взята из вопроса автора. `clipPath` взят из моего первого ответа.

При такой технике приходится немного позиционировать clipPath: увеличивать и сдвигать

`<path transform="translate(-150 0) scale(2.8)"`

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  
  background: rgba(74,92,18,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(74,92,18,1)), color-stop(39%, rgba(74,92,18,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(36,43,9,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);

}


#maskandgif{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  
  
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip-path);
  clip-path: url(#clip-path);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="0" width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <defs>
          <clipPath  id="clip-path">
            <path transform="translate(-150 0) scale(2.8)" d="M300.1 5.8L250.4 65.8 285.1 65.8 200.2 132.6 274.7 131 190.4 217.4 239 217.4 150 291.4 291.3 291.4 291.3 329.7 308.4 329.2 307.8 291.4 450.1 291.4 375.1 217.4 423.2 217.4 332.2 130 400.5 131.6 309.4 65.8 350.3 65.8 300.1 5.8z" fill="red" stroke="black"/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
      </svg>
      <div id="maskandgif">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1450175178156-cb9ecd3da179?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>
```

### Анимация клипа

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  
  background: rgba(74,92,18,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(74,92,18,1)), color-stop(39%, rgba(74,92,18,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(36,43,9,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(74,92,18,1) 0%, rgba(74,92,18,1) 39%, rgba(36,43,9,1) 100%);

}


#maskandgif{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  
  
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip-path);
  clip-path: url(#clip-path);
}
```

```html
 <div class="box">
      <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="0" width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <defs>
          <clipPath  id="clip-path">
            <path transform="translate(-100 0) scale(2.15)"  d="M300.1 5.8L250.4 65.8 285.1 65.8 200.2 132.6 274.7 131 190.4 217.4 239 217.4 150 291.4 291.3 291.4 291.3 329.7 308.4 329.2 307.8 291.4 450.1 291.4 375.1 217.4 423.2 217.4 332.2 130 400.5 131.6 309.4 65.8 350.3 65.8 300.1 5.8z" fill="red" stroke="black" >
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  type="scale" dur="14s" values="1;2.8" fill="freeze" /> 

        </path> 
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
      </svg>
      <div id="maskandgif">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4qIQ.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @HamSter посмотри ещё один ответ